# Cocoapods installation for YouTube integration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoapods

I need to install cocoapods for youtube integration,i used this link http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2 for reference

This is my podfile

```
               //////////////////////////////////////////
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'testyoutube' do

pod "YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper", "~> 0.1"

end

target 'testyoutubeTests' do

end

                //////////////////////////////////////////
```

and i am getting this error code when i tried to install pods

```
Ansals-Mac-mini:testyoutube ansalantony$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.37.0.rc.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

[!] Unable to find a specification for `YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper (~> 0.1)`
Ansals-Mac-mini:testyoutube ansalantony$
```

I have installed pod with pod 'AFNetworking', '2.2.1' but I am getting error when I'm trying to install pod

```
"YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper", "~> 0.1"
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

u can use this link for referance : https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper

use these pod command instead of the old one
 `pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.1"`

Answer (score 16):

Replace your `pod` line with this one:

```
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.1"
```

Answer (score 7):

The latest version is 0.1.4:

```
pod "youtube-ios-player-helper", "~> 0.1.4"
```

Notice that everything is *lowercase*.

Comment: `~>` means version equal or greater than. So even if your write `'~> 0.1'` it will still download the latest version(currently 0.1.5).

Answer (score 0):

> Unable to find a specification for `YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper (~> 0.1)`.

It actually translates to: **`no pod file available with the name 'YouTube-Player-iOS-Helper'`**. Also **('~> 0.1')** represents only the version of the pod file.

In this case you can check the the project’s **[GitHub page](https://github.com/youtube/youtube-ios-player-helper)** and get the current pod file with latest version.

Currently **pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 0.1.4'** is available.

You can also use only `pod 'youtube-iso-player-helper'` (without including any specific version) and it will get updated when its version gets updated by the pod development team.